# jQuery get multiple attributes value

Tags: html, jquery, image, attributes, src

I have the following HTML code

```
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image2.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image3.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image4.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image5.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image6.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image7.jpg" class="img">
```

With JQuery i want to get data-src value and put it on src

Something like this

```
$("*.img").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
```

Thanks For ur Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each` to achieve this.

```js
  $("img").each((i, e) => {
    $(e).attr("src", $(e).attr("data-src"))
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image1.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image2.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image3.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image4.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image5.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image6.jpg" class="img">
<img src="" data-src="https://example.com/image7.jpg" class="img">
```